# Find and replace any number in href value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, href

This is my current code, which does not work:

```
$( "#cart_url" ).attr('href', this.href.replace( "ProductCode=TFLG1&Qty.TFLG1="/^[0-9]+$/"&", "test" ));
```

I'm not exactly sure how to write the syntax.  Where I have "/^[0-9]+$/" , I'm just trying to replace any result of any number with "test".

Further information:

```
$( "#cart_url" ).attr('href', this.href.replace( "ProductCode=TFLG1&Qty.TFLG1=345&", "test" ));
```

This code would work fine, but the number '345' could be anything from 1-1000, so I need to find and replace that number dynamically instead of writing this function 1000 times.

Comment: Please show an example input and example output.

Comment: Example:

'ProductCode=TFLG1&Qty.TFLG1=345&'

Would be converted to:

'test'

But the number '345' in the above example could be anything from 1-1000, which is set based on a slider value.

Comment: So if any number between `1` and `1000` is present in the `href` (or present in *a particular place* in the `href`?) the *entire `href`* should be converted to `'test'`?

Comment: If any number between 1 and 1000 is present in that very specific spot in that very specific string, that entire string "ProductCode=TFLG1&Qty.TFLG1=345&"should be converted to 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the pattern you need is something like `/[Qty.TFLG1][\d]+(?=&)/g`

It would work this way:

```
var pattern =/[Qty.TFLG1][\d]+(?=&)/g;
$("#cart_url").attr("href", this.href.replace( pattern, "test" ));
```

That would return something like:

```
ProductCode=TFLG1&Qty.TFLG1=test&
```